# SQL: convert string to math operator

Tags: sql, sql-server

**This is what I am trying to do:**

```
select Id, Operator form MathOperator
```

**Results:**

```
ID | Operator
-----------
1  |  '+' 
2  |  '-'
```

***And somehow to do this:**

```
declare @operator char(2)=  
     (select MathOperatorSymbol from MathOperator Where MathOperatorId = 1) 

select 1 @operator  2  -- should be as: select 1+2
```

Is it possible?

Comment: This is not possible unless you use dynamic SQL.

Comment: `select  1>=2`  will raise an error anyway.  As well as `select '1'-'2'` Generally it will not work unless you first check operator and arguments comprise a valid combination.

Comment: Using `.query` can solve problem of `>` and `<` operators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use dynamic SQL

```
exec('select 1'+ @operator + ' 2')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using dynamic SQL:

```
declare @operator char(2) =  
     (select MathOperatorSymbol from MathOperator Where MathOperatorId = 1); 

declare @sql nvarchar(max) = 'select 1 @operator  2  -- should be as: select 1+2';

set @sql = replace(@sql, '@operator', @operator);

exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

Of course, `<=` and `>=` will not work in this context, so they would generate an error.

Answer (score 1):

yes it's  posible. You can use **Dynamic Query**

**Sample :**

```
BEGIN
DECLARE @STRQUERY NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @OPERATOR CHAR(2)
 SET @OPERATOR = '+';
 SET @STRQUERY = 'SELECT 1' + @OPERATOR + '2';

 EXEC (@STRQUERY)

END
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are only supporting simple calculations (`Num1 Operator Num2`) you can use a [case expression](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765(v=sql.105).aspx) to select the correct operator.

```
SELECT
    CASE Operator
        WHEN '+' THEN Num1 + Num2
        WHEN '-' THEN Num1 - Num2
        ELSE NULL
    END AS Result
FROM
    MyTable
;
```

If MyTable contains:

```
Num1    Operator    Num2
1       +           1
1       -           1
```

The query would return:

```
Result
2
0
```

Make sure you are storing your values using the appropriate data types.  If not you might find the query returns unexpected results.

If you need to support to more advanced options consider dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0):

The one way is to use XML ([.query](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191474.aspx)) and dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max),
        @val1 float = 1,
        @val2 float = 2,
        @oper int =1

;WITH MathOperator  AS (
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES
(1, '+' ),
(2, '-'),
(3, '*'),
(4, 'div'), --instead of /
(5, '>'),
(6, '<')
) as t(ID, Operator)
)

SELECT @sql = N'
DECLARE @x xml = ''''; 
SELECT @x.query('''+CAST(@val1 as nvarchar(max))+' '+Operator+' '+CAST(@val2 as nvarchar(max))+''');'
FROM MathOperator
WHERE id = @oper

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

If you pass `1` and `2` with different `@oper` you will get:

```
oper    result
+       3
-       -1
*       2
/       0.5
>       true
<       false
```